# Mysql set algebra operations

Tags: mysql

I have an unusally worded Question that even my lab professor wasnt 100% sure on what it wants, but does have some idea which ill bring up. The given question is "A query listed below must be implemented with set algebra operations: Find a code of all customers who ordered product Tofu or product Tunnbrod"

My Professor believes its asking for a UNION JOIN  in which i have come up with the following:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE
FROM ORDERS
WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = ORDER_ID

UNION ALL

SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
FROM ORDER_DETAIL
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'Tunnbrod' AND ‘Tofu’;
```

This code acts like a List and just makes Tunnbrod a customer code, so im unsure of what i need to actually do. My professor did mention joing the or and and operands, in which i tried and failed to get the expected results.

below are the tables for reference

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         DECIMAL(10,2)           DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
(
    ORDER_ID         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_NAME     VARCHAR(40)    NOT NULL,
    UNIT_PRICE       DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    QUANTITY         DECIMAL(9) NOT NULL    DEFAULT 1 ,
    DISCOUNT         DECIMAL(4,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_DETAIL PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT_NAME FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_NAME) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_QUANTITY CHECK (QUANTITY > 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_ORDER_DETAIL_DISCOUNT CHECK (DISCOUNT between 0 and 1)
);
```

Comment: I would say a join would be the way to go not a union.

Comment: i have another question but i cant offically post it. How does one go about doing a self join as a nested Query?

Answer (score 1):

This is a strangely formulated question to an otherwise simple thing:

```
Select * orders inner join order_details where PRODUCT_NAME = 'Tunnbrod' OR  PRODUCT_NAME = ‘Tofu’
```

you can, of course, explicitly use `UNION` instead of `OR`:

```
Select * orders inner join order_details where PRODUCT_NAME = 'Tunnbrod'
UNION
Select * orders inner join order_details where PRODUCT_NAME = ‘Tofu’
```

Comment: The simple part is explicitly forbidden; the lesson is on unions and other set operations, so the second statement is the one being solicited.

Comment: i have another question but i cant offically post it. How does one go about doing a self join as a nested Query?

Comment: You use aliases, like Select * from table1 A inner join table1 B on (A.id = B.fk)